# Is it possible to run a job multiple times, once for each value in a variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a dynamic list for which I'd like to run a given job for each item in the list.

Basically this is a list of tags (~20) for a docker container that would ideally all be processed concurrently.  As the list of tags can change I'd like to define the list once and consume it in multiple places, including in the jobs definition.

On Travis-CI this is known as [Matrix Expansion](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/#matrix-expansion), but I've been unable to find a similar feature on Gitlab CI.

Comment: I dont think gitlab ci has this feature, I would try writing a script that does what you need

Answer (score 0):

use the keyword [parallel:matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#parallelmatrix)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31350538)